# How to export a texture from Maya to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, textures, maya

I am trying to export a model from Maya with animation but when I import into unity I am getting the model but the texture is not there. From the internet I found that while importing the model I need to enable media that also does not work for me.

Comment: This question is off topic for StackOverflow (see what's on topic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try posting this on GameDev: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ However, as small experience as I have, I think the textures don't follow the model in none of the file formats. You need to import your texture separately in Unity and apply it on the model's material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Maya, you can check **EmbeddMedia** checkbox when you export FBX. In this case all models and textures will be automatically imported to the Unity. But the FBX file will weight more size.([ref](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/47733/importing-from-maya-textures-gone.html))

OR

As Nika Said,

1. First Add your texture into unity
2. then add Your fbx